# Replacing Django SMTP with third party email triggers/events/attributes

Tags: django, email, django-authentication

Password reset is called here in the URLs file:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', 
       auth_views.password_reset, {
           'post_reset_redirect': 'auth_password_reset_done',
           'template_name': 'auth/password_reset_form.html',
           'password_reset_form': AccountPasswordResetForm,
           'email_template_name': 'auth/password_reset_email.html',
           },
       name='auth_password_reset'),
```

Rather than send the email “password_reset_email.html” via SMTP I need to send some events and attributes to my third party email provider.
How would I go about doing this? Maybe by changing password_reset() function? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a new function in my app `views.py`:

```
def my_password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do the additional bussiness here
    send_some_events()
    # And then do the password reset as usual.
    auth.views.password_reset(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Change the call at `urls.py` to:

```
url(r'^password/reset/$', 
   my_app.views.my_password_reset, ...
```

Comment: of course! haha so simple. I was going to copy the whole password reset function but this is a much better solution. Thanks!